# Incorrect output report viewer printing

Tags: c#, .net, printing, reportviewer, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with a Tablix control on it. there are other fields above the tablix so it starts a 1/3 of the way down the page. When the tablix size does not reach the end of the page everything is good. But when the tablix size causes the tablix to go onto the next page i get issues. The preview of the report looks correct, and when I export to PDF or Word, it appears correct. but when I print the tablix starts on a new blank page and does not span from the first page to the second. I checked the tablix properties and the keep on one page property is set to false.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was that the rows were in a group that had the keep together property set to true. I did not realize by defaults the rows are set in a group. changing this property fixed this issue.

Comment: ahh. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to fix your margins and ensure that the width of the report (based on the ruler at the top of the report area) is less than the size of paper you would want to use.

In order to set the margins, right click outside the report (in the blue area) and click on Report Properties. It will be on the bottom of the Page Setup tab. You will need to make sure that the margins and the length of the report (from the ruler measurements in the report builder UI) is less than the width of the paper size. So if you are using 8.5x11 paper for the report, and 1" margins on both sides, you would need to have your report's width at most, 6.5" wide or else it will cut off and create a new line and just look awful.

---

EDIT: As the information above wasn't useful, I went looking for an answer and found this:

> If a physical page break occurs through report items that must be kept together, the items that must be kept together are moved to the next page.
>
> Because of page size constraints, it may not be possible to keep all the items together or to repeat items. If that occurs, the renderer might ignore certain rules for repeating with another item in order to allow the report item to fit on the page.

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677573(v=sql.100).aspx That is a rule that is applied to the exported files that have Hard-Page Break Renderers, which include PDF and Images.

Comment: the issues doesn't have to do with width. Whats happening is if the tablix has to many rows and gets to long for the allotted space about 2/3 the page, instead of continuing on the next page it creates the entire tablix on the next page. But it is only doing this when printed. The viewer and when exported display the report correctly

Comment: @kds6253 ah I'm sorry. Look at the properties of the tablix in question. Is KeepTogether true or false? If true, set it to false and try again.

Comment: it is stated in my question that i already have that property set to false. but thanks for the idea

Comment: @kds6253 I edited my answer to include more pertinent information. The only suggestion then is to look at the settings in MS Word when printing because it should appear in Word the same way it shows up in the report viewer.

Comment: I appreciate the further digging on your part but I am confused because when I export to PDF i get the correct layout. the tablix fills as much as possible on the from the page and the rest is on the second. but when I do a physical print it just throws the entire tablix on the second page. After reading that article it sounds like exporting to pdf should behave the same as a physical print and that is not the case for me.

Comment: Its almost like when physically printing the tablix is acting as an object that must stay together, but this only happens on a physical print and the keep together property is definitly set to false.

Comment: @kds6253 ya it's definitely a mystery. I wish I could be more of a help.